# IntelliJ IDEA won't run Flutter app

Tags: intellij-idea, flutter

I am experiencing a strange issue with Flutter development and IntelliJ IDEA. I am developing a flutter application with IntelliJ IDEA 2017 1.4 Build number IC-171.4694.23, I am not able to run application on connected Android device, when I run the application, it shows a background process running "Running gradle assembleDebug... " and then the process stops, nothing happens although I was able to run and debug it earlier.
Solution tried,

1. Disabling/ enabling adb plugin.
2. Disabling/ enabling developer options and usb debugging.
3. Re-installing flutter.

I tried with android emulator also, same thing happens. So I think the problem is not with the device. Any help is appreciated.

**Update:**

This issue happens when I add image_picker plugin to my pubspec.yaml.

```
  dependencies:
    flutter:
      sdk: flutter
   image_picker:
```

Comment: Can you run your flutter app via `flutter run` using the command line ?

Comment: i did, no luck. Also I made a new flutter app, that is running and installing fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is `flutter run` failing with the following error?

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred configuring project ':app'.
> Failed to notify project evaluation listener.
   > Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':app:_debugApkCopy'.
      > Could not find com.github.esafirm.android-image-picker:imagepicker:1.5.0.
        Required by:
            project :app > project :image_picker
   > Could not get unknown property 'compileDebugJavaWithJavac' for project ':app' of type org.gradle.api.Project.
```

If so, you can fix this issue by modifying your `build.gradle` as described in the [image_picker](https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/image_picker) documentation.

```
allprojects {
   repositories {
       jcenter()
       maven { url "https://maven.google.com" }
       maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }    // add this line
   }
}
```

Comment: That did the trick, but I was not getting any exception, the build process won't complete and stopped without any throwing any exception.